# What are my options for repairing a rusted galvanized steel flue?

Tags: chimney, rust-removal, rust, rust-proofing

How difficult is this rust to clean up? Will I need a full replacement?

[image]

Comment: @isherwood Yes I do have attic access. So this looks more like a replacement than something like treating it and scrubbing it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the condition of the pipe, which I can't assess from my house, you'll need to either recoat it or replace it.

Hit it with a wire brush and see what's left when it's cleaned up. If it's still solid, consider recoating it with galvanizing paint.

If it's junk, take a look in your attic for the nearest joint. Decide whether you're able to detach it for replacement. If not, come back with more specific questions about your chosen strategy.